# Export datatable to csv and import to client without saving in server

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, export

I want to export the data to csv format and  then allow user to choose open / save to the client system. But csv should not be saved in server.

I have used this code:

```
this.Response.Clear();
this.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
this.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + sFileName + "\"");
this.Response.TransmitFile(FilePath);
this.Response.Flush();
this.Response.End();
```

But this is not working.

Comment: Well, clearly `Response.TransmitFile()` "won't work" if there's no file on the server.  Where is your CSV data?  Just write it directly to the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David suggests, just try streaming your CSV content directly to the Response: -

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=data.csv");
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        Response.Write(stringContainingCSVData);
        Response.End();
```

Comment: can you explain more about streaming csv directly to the response with sample.

Comment: The above code is an example ? "stringContainingCSVData" is the csv data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Get Your Data in DataTable and use this function. It works fine.

```
public void ExportToCSVFile(DataTable dt, string file_name)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
         "attachment;filename='" + file_name + "'.csv");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/text";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
        {
            sb.Append(dt.Columns[k].ColumnName + ',');
        }
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                sb.Append(dt.Rows[i][k].ToString() + ',');
            }
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }
        Response.Output.Write(sb.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help. This code i have already tried , but the Response.End() gives error "Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack".

Comment: If i replace response.End() to Response.ClearContent() then another error throws "Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed."

Comment: You can't do this from inside an UpdatePanel - not easily anyway. If the button to trigger the action is inside an UpdatePanel, you can't stream content this way without (quite a bit of) additional effort.